# Replace XML text

Tags: jquery, xml

I am trying to create a video site that has a row of images at the top which each represent a video file and below, a placeholder for the video and title. On pressing these images I need them to change the video file and also replace the title. There are 50+ videos, so would my best bet be to list the titles in an XML file and load the titles from there?
And if so, what is the best way to go about this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be much better to have the video titles in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format:

```
videoTitles = ['Title 1', 'Title 2', ...];

$.each(videoTitles, function(n, title) {
  // Do something with the title
});
```

You can also easily use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) to read the titles from a service.

For changing the title, you can use HTML like this:

```
<div class="video-thumbnail" title="Video Title 1"><img src="video thumbnail 1" ></div>
<div class="video-thumbnail" title="Video Title 2"><img src="video thumbnail 2" ></div>
```

The title attribute can be populated with javascript or server-side script. Then in jQuery:

```
$(".video-thumbnail").click(function() {
  var titleClicked = $(this).attr("title");
  $("#SelectedVideoTitle").html(titleClicked);
});
```

Comment: Thank you.any ideas on how to change the text when clicking on the "menu" images?

Comment: It works now. Kind of. But only the first image works, all of the other images have no effect.

Comment: See my edited jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7dhka/1/ Your error is that you've used the same id for more than one elements. I've replaced header_image to be a class name and not an id.